# How to do http post with payload in java

Tags: java, web, http-post, httprequest, httpclient

When I click a button on webpage I get following information in developer tools:

```
Request URL:https://example.com/path/eventAction.do
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

and Request headers like below:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1600
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----
WebKitFormBoundaryZ9ymd7fGOwOFpELi
Cookie:JSESSIONID=C1rX...
```

and Request payload like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZ9ymd7fGOwOFpELi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="example1"

FILTER_900000
------WebKitFormBoundaryZ9ymd7fGOwOFpELi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="example2"


------WebKitFormBoundaryZ9ymd7fGOwOFpELi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="example3"

08/03/2018
```

How can I send this http post with Apache HttpClient or is there any other method to imitate button click event with java code..

Comment: [Here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payload parameter can be submitted with `HttpPost` request by preparing a `JSON` object as string and calling `HttpPost`'s `setEntity` method.

```
payload = "{" +"\"fsName\": \"Peel\", " + "\"name\": \"John\", " +  "\"path\": \"/" + accountName + "/invoice/" + sdf2.format(todayDate.toDate()) + "\", " + "}";

strEntity = new StringEntity(payload); 

HttpPost().setEntity(strPayload).
```